# Trade-off between hypervolume and diameter of $d$-dimensional shapes having a hypercubic smallest bounding box

Tags: co.combinatorics, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, euclidean-geometry, combinatorial-optimization

Given any $d$-dimensional shape $X$, let $V(X)$ be its $d$-dimensional volume, and let $\ell(X)$ be the length of the longest line segment connecting two points of $X$.

Let $\mathcal{S}_C$ be the set of all $d$-dimensional shapes such that their minimum bounding box is a $d$-dimensional cube $C$. I am interested in quantifying the trade-off between $\frac{V(X)}{V(C)}$ and $\frac{\ell(X)}{\ell(C)}$ over $X\in\mathcal{S}_C$ (informally, how much $\frac{V(X)}{V(C)}$ can be large while $\frac{\ell(X)}{\ell(C)}$ is small).

**Question:** Can we prove that for $d\gg 1$ and for all $X\in\mathcal{S}_C$ there exists a constant $c$ such that the following inequality always holds?
$$\left(\frac{V(X)}{V(C)}\right)^{\tfrac1d}\le c\cdot\frac{\ell(X)}{\ell(C)}$$

Comment: A candidate for the extreme is $X=$ the sphere.

Comment: Thank you @JosephO'Rourke. I corrected the typo. Yes, the sphere, but I am realizing now that I am especially interested in the last question I just added: I would like to be sure that it is not possible to have a solid $X\in\mathcal{S}_C$ with a $\ell(\cdot)$ ratio small (like the one for the sphere) and a $V(\cdot)$ ratio large (that the sphere does not have).

Comment: For $X$ a $d$-ball, $\frac{\ell(X)}{\ell(C)} = d^{-1/2}$ and $\frac{V(X)}{V(C)} = \frac{\pi^{d/2}}{2^d\Gamma(d/2 + 1)}$.  For large $d$, this is about $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi d}} (\pi e/2d)^{d/2}$

Comment: Thank you @S.Carnahan, is it true for all solids $X\in\mathcal{S}_C$ with such a low value for $\frac{\ell(X)}{\ell(C)}$ (e.g., like the one of the hypersphere), we always have a very small value for $\frac{V(X)}{V(C)}$? My first two questions are basically: what is the trade-off between these two ratios over all solids $X\in\mathcal{S}_C$?

Comment: I cannot find a good reference with a proof, but some web searching suggests that if $\frac{\ell(X)}{\ell(C)} = d^{-1/2}$, then $X$ is contained in a body of constant width, and that volumes of such bodies are bounded above by that of the ball.

Comment: Thank you @S.Carnahan, this is very interesting and corroborates my opinion about the conjecture in the third question. Do you have any idea about how to prove it?

Comment: I removed the first two questions, because the third one is sufficiently significant (and I guess it is an easier problem). Hence, there is only one question now.

Comment: @S.Carnahan basically I am interested in the maximum value of $\frac{V(X)}{V(C)}$ for the whole the range $\frac{\ell(X)}{\ell(C)}\in[d^{-1/2},1]$. What if, for instance, $\frac{\ell(X)}{\ell(C)}=\log(d)$? It is still true that $\left(\frac{V(X)}{V(C)}\right)^{1/d}\le \frac{\ell(X)}{\ell(C)}$?

Comment: Are you sure you want $\log d$ there?  It's only less than 1 for $d=2$.

Comment: @S. Carnahan, sorry, there was a typo in my comment. By writing $\log(d)$ I meant $\log(d)^{-1}$, which is in fact in the range I wrote I am interested in: $[d^{-1/2}, 1]$. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: From what I said it follows that you always have $(V(X)/V(C))^{1/d}\le (1+o(1))K(\ell(X)/\ell(C))$ where the best $K$ is $\sqrt{\pi e/2}$ if $\ell\le\sqrt{\frac d{2\log d}}$, when the intersection is essentially the entire ball of diameter $\ell$, and then it gradually drops to $\sqrt 3$ at $\ell=\sqrt{d/3}$, when the intersection becomes essentially the entire unit cube. After that nothing interesting happens but the exact value of $K$ in the range $[\sqrt{\frac d{2\log d}},\sqrt{\frac d 3}]$ is still unclear to me though, I suspect, it is not too important for the question as asked.

Comment: Thank you a LOT @fedja! Is it possible, in your opinion, to state that $\sqrt{\pi e / 2}$ is un upper bound for $K$ which holds for all values of $\ell$? As you perhaps already understood, I am interested in finding a general upper bound of $\frac{\left(V(X)/V(C)\right)^{1/d}}{\left(\ell(X)/\ell(C)\right)}$. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, Penelope, you cannot go worse than if you just consider an unrestricted ball of diameter $\ell$ against the unit cube, so $\sqrt{\pi e/2}$ is a sure upper bound. The point was rather that it usually doesn't get much better than that even with all the extra conditions you imposed.

Comment: OK, great! Hence, if $\frac{\left(V(X)/V(C)\right)^{1/d}}{\ell(X)/\ell(C)}\le \sqrt{\pi e /2}$ always holds, could you please add this part in your answer draft so that I can validate it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit too long for the comment box, so I'm posting it as an answer.

The worst case scenario is when $X$ is the intersection of a ball of radius $r\ge 1$ with the cube $C=[-1,1]^d$. Indeed, if we take the difference body $\frac{X-X}{2}$ of any body $X$ contained in the cube and of diameter $\ell=2r$, we'll get a body contained in the cube and also in the ball of radius $r$ and the volume will not decrease by Brunn-Minkowski. Also, since any such body contains the unit ball, the standard cube is, indeed, the minimal box for it. Since $\frac{\sqrt n}r X\supset C$, we see that for that body the reverse inequality always holds.

It would be nice to find a decent approximation for the volume of that intersection to see what happens in the regime when $r/\sqrt d$ stays fixed and $d\to\infty$, say.

Comment: I guess when $1\le r\le\sqrt{2}$ then the intersection is the ball with cut $2d$ hats of height $r-1$, so its volume can be easily calculated. When $\sqrt{2}\le r\le \sqrt{d}$ then the intersection seems to be the cube with spherically cut $2^d$ corners. Maybe there is a way to calculate a volume of such corner too, for instance, by induction with respect to $d$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky your intuition is correct and is explained here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1996000/intersection-of-hypercube-and-hypersphere However, it is not clear how to formally exploit this recursion for the final goal of the problem (for instance by using an induction based on this recursion).